# Role based page redirect not working in 'OnLoggedIn' event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

Good Morning Everyone!

Can someone please help me to solve an issue that I am facing while trying to redirect the user, based on specific role, to a different page as I have wasted a day behind it and it was still not sorted :(.

No matter with what role I login, the system redirects me to the same page i.e.: "TESTPAGE1.aspx", when I use this code in 'OnLoggedIn' event. But the same works fine in 'on page load' event. I want this action to take place only once i.e. only when a user logins using the user name and password and not whenever a user visits the page in question or refreshes it and so I am not placing it in 'on page load' event.

What I am actually trying to achieve here is:

- There are two tabs on 'Login Page' 1> For Client Login and 2 > For Staff Login.
- Whenever a Staff tries to login using the Client Tab:

  > They should be logged out and redirected to TESTPAGE1.aspx, where I'll convey
  >   the necessary message.
- Whenever a Client tries to login using the Client Tab:

  > They should successfully loggedin and redirected to TESTPAGE2.aspx, which will be
  >   my home page.

```html
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" >
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"  EnableViewState="true" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" > 
                            </asp:Login>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server"  FormatString="You are already logged in as {0}" />
                        
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                  </asp:LoginView>
```

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


            if (!User.IsInRole("Client"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/FAQs.aspx");
            }
            else
            {

                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }




}
```

Comment: Is it possible to debug your code and see what roles the User object is in. Its possible that you may be in multiple roles at once. I.e role X and role Client

Comment: check the redirections with developer tools of the browser or with fiddler or wireshark. It is possible that you go to faq page then to the test page 1

Comment: Spaceman - I am logged in into only a 'Client' role. Is it the Anonymous that is causing the issue??

Comment: Oguz Ozgul - FAQ page is the test page one and everytime I login, I am redirected to the FAQ page that is Test page 1.

Comment: Any help will help friends!

Answer (score 0):

Yo! Finally I managed to make it right using the below code:

```
   protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Client"))
        Response.Redirect("~/TestONE.aspx");
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Technician"))
        Response.Redirect("~/TestTWO.aspx");



}
```